# What is the default source, when --source isn't specified?

Tags: linux, iptables

If I have two NICs on my server, what is the difference of

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE --source 192.168.0.0/24
```

?

When `--source` isn't specified, what does iptables then use as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is any address 0.0.0.0. If you run `iptables -t nat -L -v -n`, you will see something like this:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   15   923 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: So it is independent of NIC's?

Comment: More precisely, it is 0.0.0.0/0 — a zero address with a zero mask, which matches any IPv4 address, effectively disabling the filtering on the packet source address. Note that the `--source` option specifies a packet filtering condition (which packets should be passed to the specified iptables target), and does not affect the target behavior (for `MASQUERADE` the source address assigned to packets passing through NAT will be determined according to the routing table).

Answer (score 0):

The system will follow the normal rules to define the source address as the machine's local address that is "closest" to the destination. In practice, that will usually mean that the source will be the normal source address for the route to the destination's next hop. This will typically be the IP address assigned to the interface the post-NAT packet is sent out on.

Comment: This describes the `MASQUERADE` target behavior in general, which does not change when `--source` (or another packet matching option) is specified.

Comment: That's what the question asked. "When --source isn't specified, what does iptables then use as default?" "What is the default source, when --source isn't specified?"

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of using MASQUERADE is so that it will modify the source address to that of the interface it is going out of; if the outgoing interface has a static IP, use SNAT, don't use MASQUERADE; it causes all connections to be forgotten whenever the interface goes down and is essentially intended for any interface that has a changing IP.

if you wish to *filter* based on the actual source of the packet, you should use `-s x.x.x.x/xx` before the `-j MASQUERADE`